# Updating multiple documents with mongoose not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a Node/Express API using Mongoose, where I am trying to update subdocuments within multiple documents.

Essentially I have a user with a profile that has multiple phone numbers that they can share with another contact.

Each contact has a profile.contacts[] section, that has profile.contacts.phones[] section.

When the main user sharing his/her phone number with other users changes his/her number, I want to update the profile.contacts.phones[] section in all documents, where the _id of that phone number matches.

Here is my code:

```
  Profile.update({'contacts.phones._id':req.body._id}, {
    Profile.contacts.phones.phone_number:req,body.phone_number,
    Profile.contacts.phones.phone_type:req.body.phone_type
  }, {multi:true}, function(err, result){
    if(err)
      res.send(err)
    res.json(result);
  })
```

Here is a sample "Profile" document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59c09dca981de33d180df943"),
    "last_name" : "Sam",
    "first_name" : "Sam",
    "owner_id" : "59c09dca981de33d180df940",
    "contacts" : [
        {
            "first_name" : "Joe",
            "last_name" : "Public",
            "_id" : ObjectId("59c09dca981de33d180df944"),
            "phones" : [
                {
                    "phone_number" : "2067155803",
                    "phone_type" : "home",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("59bca0b55481370985cac29a")
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Based on what I see in the documentation, this should work...

Thanks for any insight!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would need to use the positional operator to update an object in an array **$** that matched the query.

However, this cannot be used for nested arrays:

> The positional $ operator cannot be used for queries which traverse more than one array, such as queries that traverse arrays nested within other arrays, because the replacement for the $ placeholder is a single value.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

You might have to consider restructuring your documents.

Comment: Thanks Steve, but I'm getting the following error: "cannot use the part (contacts of contacts.phones.phone_type) to traverse the element 
{  
   contacts:[  
      {  
         first_name:"Joe",
         last_name:"Public",
         _id:ObjectId('59c09dca981de33d180df944')
         phones:[  
            {  
               phone_number:"2067155803",
               phone_type:"home",
               _id:ObjectId('59bca0b55481370985cac29a')
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}

Comment: I think the problem lies with the nested arrays: **contacts** and then **phones**.

Comment: Thanks for your help Steve. I ended up breaking out the contacts into a separate document as you suggested.

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: Hey Steve, If you have a chance, I have a related question... kind of. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46348270/mongoose-update-not-working-for-me. If you get a chance...